# HBase bulk load hangs with 2 files remaining

Tags: hbase

I'm bulk loading HBase from Spark, writing to HFiles via HFileOutputFormat2. All is well until the bulk load when it seems to hang on the final couple files

```
INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.tool.LoadIncrementalHFiles: 
Split occurred while grouping HFiles, 
retry attempt 632 with 2 files remaining 
to group or split
```

Any ideas? Not sure if my HFiles are skewed? Too large? (They are only in the 10s of MBs and my hbase.region.max.filesize=10GB)

Comment: split can occur due to many factors, not just max hfile size. read more about hbase split policy and figure out how to tune for your workload.

Comment: Figured this out. All my records seemed to be hitting the same two region servers. I partitioned better via hashing the first part of my key and it solved this.