# LoadIncrementalHFiles: Split occurred while grouping HFiles

Tags: apache-spark, hbase, bulk-load

I implemented a Spark(v2.4) application that processes raw data and stores it into containerized Hbase(v2.1).
I would like to bulk load the data into Hbase and for that purpose, I use [apache/hbase-connectors](https://github.com/apache/hbase-connectors). I followed this [example](https://github.com/apache/hbase-connectors/blob/fddb433e07ab520a4c0e593a74842901bd41f598/spark/hbase-spark/src/test/java/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/spark/TestJavaHBaseContext.java#L446).

I pre-split Hbase regions to 10 and transformed each key by hashing and applying modulo upon the hash value, then concatenated it as a prefix to the key.
for example: key = a123, newKey = 0_a123 (assume: hash(a123) mod 10 = 0).

When I run my Spark app, I can see that the Hfiles has been created but when I'm trying to doBulkLoad with LoadIncrementalHFiles I get the following error:

> LoadIncrementalHFiles: Split occurred while grouping HFiles, retry
> attempt 12 with 10 files remaining to group or split

I saw the following [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53673720/hbase-bulk-load-hangs-with-2-files-remaining) which I think is similar to what I have already done.

1. Why does LoadIncrementalHFiles fail?
2. Should the Hfiles be on the container as well before doing the LoadIncrementalHFiles in a containerized environment?
3. Should I pre-split Hbase regions differently?
4. Is there any formula to calculate the number of regions?

In Hbase logs I can see the following error:

> regionserver.SecureBulkLoadManager: Failed to complete bulk load
> java.io.FileNotFoundException: File ... does not exist

Comment: Someone who can help?

Answer (score 2):

The problem was with the location of the Hfiles.

I read Hbase logs and saw it looks for the Hfiles which were on my host machine, FileNotFoundException was thrown.

I mount the Hfiles directory to the Hbase container and the problem was solved.

Comment: Thank you, it solved perfectly my problem !!

Answer (score 0):

Since you can hash your rows for better distribution, you might want to pre-split your table by using the Hex region splitter utility. It will automatically figure out how to split the table nicely across the hexadecimal space, based on how many region servers you have. Maybe this can help you bypass the unnecessary splitting on the fly. You can use it from command-line like this:

```
hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.RegionSplitter TableName HexStringSplit -c 10 -f CF
```

- TableName is your table name
- 10 is the number of region servers you have in the cluster
- CF is the name of the Column Family to create

The table shouldn't exist when you are launching this.

Comment: VS_FF first of all thanks for your help. I did the pre-split as you suggested but I keep getting the same error, do you have any other idea? I forgot to mention that I run containerized Hbase instance (will update this information in the question).

Comment: Not sure if containers make a difference here. Maybe instead of using LoadIncrementalHfiles you should try more straighforward means of uploading data into HBase from Spark, such as via the SHC connector. There's lot of documentation out there on how to use it, and it's very robust.

Comment: I published the solution to my problem. Thanks for your help!